# Checkbox onclick filtering on the same page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query

Currently I'm doing that with GET method. I think that I have complicated it too much. On page load all check box are checked, and when users uncheck checkbox, a post with that taxonomy is filtered out. My code is currently working and here it is:

Setting checkbox checked:

```
    $actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";      
    if ( $actual_link == 'https://www.example.com/') {
        $var_check = 1;
    }
```

Checkboxes:

```
    <form action="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" method="GET" id="filter">      
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='f'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($face =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite facebook" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Facebook</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='t'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="t" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($twitter=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite twitter2" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Twitter</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='te'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="te" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($telegram=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite telegram2" style="margin-left:5px;"><span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Telegram</span></div><br>   
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='r'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="r" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($reddit=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite reddit" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Reddit</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='e'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="e" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($email=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite email" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Flter by Email</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='ph'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ph" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($phone=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite phone" style="margin-left:2px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Phone</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='b'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($bitcointalk=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite bitcointalk" style="margin-left:3px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by BitcoinTalk</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='k'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="k" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($kyc=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite kyc" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by KYC</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='y'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="y" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($youtube=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite youtube" style="margin-left:2px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by YouTube</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='l'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="l" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($linkedin=='1') || ($var_check == 1) )  {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite linkedin" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Flter by LinkedIn</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='eth'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($ethereum =='1')  || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="ethereum" style="margin-left:5px;">ETH<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Ethereum</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='neo'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="neo" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($neo =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="neo" style="margin-left:5px;">NEO<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by NEO</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='xml'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="xml" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($stellar =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="stellar" style="margin-left:5px;">XML<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Stellar</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='waves'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="waves" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($waves =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="waves" style="margin-left:5px;">WAVES<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Waves</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='kmd'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="kmd" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($komodo =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="komodo" style="margin-left:5px;">KMD<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Komodo</span></div><br>
        <input type='hidden' value='0' name='own'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="own" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($own =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="own" style="margin-left:5px;">OWN<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Own chain</span></div><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="req">
    </form>
```

Here is getting of the variables:

```
    if ( isset($_GET['f']) && $_GET['f'] == '1') {$face='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['f']) ) {$face = '0'; }  else {$face='facebook';}
    if ( isset($_GET['t']) && $_GET['t'] == '1' ) {$twitter='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['t']) ) {$twitter = '0'; } else {$twitter='twitter';}
    if ( isset($_GET['te']) && $_GET['te'] == '1' ) {$telegram='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['te']) ) {$telegram = '0'; } else {$telegram='telegram';}
    if ( isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] == '1' ) {$reddit='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['r']) ) {$reddit = '0'; } else {$reddit='reddit';}
    if ( isset($_GET['e']) && $_GET['e'] == '1' ) {$email='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['e']) ) {$email = '0'; } else {$email='email';}
    if ( isset($_GET['ph']) && $_GET['ph'] == '1' ) {$phone='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['ph']) ) {$phone = '0'; } else {$phone='phone';}
    if ( isset($_GET['b']) && $_GET['b'] == '1' ) {$bitcointalk='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['b']) ) {$bitcointalk = '0'; } else {$bitcointalk='bitcointalk';}
    if ( isset($_GET['k']) && $_GET['k'] == '1' ) {$kyc='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['k']) ) {$kyc = '0'; } else {$kyc='kyc';}
    if ( isset($_GET['y']) && $_GET['y'] == '1' ) {$youtube='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['y']) ) {$youtube = '0'; } else {$youtube='youtube';}
    if ( isset($_GET['l']) && $_GET['l'] == '1' ) {$linkedin='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['l']) ) {$linkedin = '0'; } else {$linkedin='linkedin';}           
    if ( isset($_GET['eth']) && $_GET['eth'] == '1' ) {$ethereum='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['eth']) ) {$ethereum = '0'; } else {$ethereum='ethereum';}
    if ( isset($_GET['neo']) && $_GET['neo'] == '1' ) {$neo='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['neo']) ) {$neo = '0'; } else {$neo='neo';}
    if ( isset($_GET['xml']) && $_GET['xml'] == '1' ) {$stellar='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['xml']) ) {$stellar = '0'; } else {$stellar='stellar';}
    if ( isset($_GET['waves']) && $_GET['waves'] == '1' ) {$waves='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['waves']) ) {$waves = '0'; }  else {$waves='waves';}
    if ( isset($_GET['kmd']) && $_GET['kmd'] == '1' ) {$komodo='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['kmd']) ) {$komodo = '0'; } else {$komodo='komodo';}
    if ( isset($_GET['own']) && $_GET['own'] == '1' ) {$own='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['own']) ) {$own = '0'; } else {$own='own';}
```

And finally the query:

```
    $tax_query_args[] = array(                  
     'relation' => 'AND',                   
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'filters',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array ($face, $twitter, $telegram, $reddit, $email, $phone, $bitcointalk, $kyc, $youtube, $linkedin),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
         ),                         
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'platform',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array ($ethereum, $neo, $stellar, $waves, $komodo, $own),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
         ),                     
    );
```

This is currently working and I'm getting the desired result. But how to do with POST method on the same page, so that URL is not changed with parameters. I suppose I will have to use AJAX, but I'm not experienced with it.

I will appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: You could change the `form` `method` to `POST`, and replace those `$_GET` with `$_POST`.

Comment: I did, but than there is a "confirm form submission..." on reload problem.

Comment: Ok, I can help you with the AJAX part; but can you post the markup/HTML of the part which displays the posts, which I suppose is after the `form`?

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary? Because it is kind a big code with lots of custom fields.

Comment: Never mind about the markup. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

But before that, the `form`'s `method` should remain as `GET`. And in the `form` markup/HTML, remove the `onchange="this.form.submit()"` from all the `checkbox` fields. Then add a standard submit button to the form; example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

[EDIT] *The submit button is not necessary.* I've updated the script so that when selecting a filter (i.e. "checking" a `checkbox`), the AJAX request is fired automatically.

Next, make sure to assign a unique ID to the posts/result `div` or container. For this example, the ID is `my-unique-ID`. (This container must *not* include the filter form.)

Now here's the script:

```
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ){
    function ajaxFilter() {
        var $form = $( 'form#filter' );

        // Disable the submit button and then remove its focus.
        $form.find( ':submit' ).prop( 'disabled', true ).blur();

        // Make sure to change my-unique-ID to the correct value.
        $( '#my-unique-ID' ).load(
            $form.attr( 'action' ) + ' #my-unique-ID',
            $form.serialize(),
            function(){
                // Enable the submit button once AJAX is complete.
                $form.find( ':submit' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
            }
        );
    }

    // Run the AJAX request upon submitting the form.
    $( 'form#filter' ).on( 'submit', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        ajaxFilter();
    } );

    // Run the AJAX request upon selecting a filter; i.e. "checking" a checkbox.
    $( ':checkbox', 'form#filter' ).on( 'change', function(){
        ajaxFilter();
    } );
} );
</script>
```

You can add the script after the posts/result container, or before the closing `</body>` tag, or somewhere else that you think is appropriate (which means jQuery must have already been loaded).

Hope that helps, and just let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to comment earlier. I was stuck on other things and I was not able to continue on this problem. I was able to solve this issue without form. In the ajax call I'm checking changes on checkboxes. Now I have to figure out how to solve pagination with ajax.

Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. =) And if you want, you can post another question for the pagination part.